# search for substring in string mysql

Tags: mysql

i have two tables of businesses , i need to select(search) between tables by business name.
for example: if in one table i have business with name "Alcantara furniture network" with id 1, in another table the name "Alcantara furniture" with id 2 . the id 2 should be returned when searched from the first table with id 1.

i have tried to write query with  LIKE but it is not helpful because it won't return the other business(id 2) . how can i search a substring in a string in mysql ?

Comment: what does the query look like?

Comment: select bussid,name from tempBusiness 
WHERE name  LIKE "%Alcantara furniture network%" . this should return business id 2 .

Answer (score 0):

You should change your like query to select what is common about the 2 values, i.e. 'Alacantara furniture':

```
select bussid,name
from tempBusiness
WHERE name LIKE '%Alcantara furniture%'
```

the string 'network' only appears in one of the names, so `WHERE name LIKE '%Alcantara furniture network%'` will only match one.

Comment: it's a very large table (with 200K rows) this is only a specific situation. in thi s row it's network the other it could be something else . is there other way beside query like ?

Comment: if you know the start of the string that can help a lot, especially if you put an index on the name column (queries with: `like '%...'` won't use any indexes).